# Big Quotation marks styled in html css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, blockquote

How would I style a quote with those huge quotation marks?

I have tried most of the examples shown online. Using Block quote with the :before and :after css styles. The issue I'm having is avoiding the use of a image in div's wrapped around text, because of responsiveness. I'm also using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Here's the CSS and the quote in HTML

```css
blockquote {
  border: none;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

blockquote h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}

blockquote h3:before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #889c0b;
}

blockquote h3:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #889c0b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <blockquote>
    <h3>Whenever you see a successful business, someone once made a courageous decision. ~Peter F. Drucker</h3>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

[image: The end result I'm trying to achieve]

The problem is getting to look like this example, although the responsiveness does sort of work. The Quotation marks are not positioned diagonally from one another.

Comment: You say you don't want to use images "because of responsiveness", yet instead you use a fixed-size (ie. non-responsive) font size for your quote marks. Make up your mind!

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your example, it appears to work perfectly.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve, because your example actually does exactly what you want to do from my point of view? Please try to explain

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It does respond fine though.It's the styling to get it to look exactly like the image thats giving me the reall hard time

Comment: @AndyReimann The code does seem to work finr. The problem is the styling part. I'm not getting the finished result like I would like in the image.

Comment: I think all you need to do is play around with different fonts just for the quotes.

Comment: A side question: why `<blockquote><h3>`?  Is that really a third-level heading under an h1 and h2?  If you're using `<h3>` just to give it size/style you should instead use a class, like `<blockquote class="pull-quote">` and then style `blockquote.pull-quote { ... }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although it's not clear after reading your question I guess you want to change the shape of quotation marks.

Pick a proper [unicode value](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quotation_mark&oldid=1190040442#Unicode_code_point_table) and add a `quotes` property. E.g.

```css
blockquote {
    border:none;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}

blockquote h3 {
font-size:21px;
}

blockquote h3:before { 
content: open-quote;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:100px;
color:#889c0b;
} 
blockquote h3:after { 
content: close-quote;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:100px;
color:#889c0b;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<blockquote><h3>Whenever you see a successful business, someone once made a courageous decision. ~Peter F. Drucker</h3></blockquote>
</div>
```

You may also want to change the `font-family` so the shape of quotation marks is more suitable to your desires.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdryt9zv/).

Comment: Rakaczy nicely done... Thanks  The only thing I have chaged with this code is to only put the font-family: in the blockquote h3:before and the blockquote h3:after classes.

Answer (score 8):

> The Quotation marks are not positioned diagonally from one another

So just position them:

```
blockquote{
    position: relative; 
}

blockquote h3:before {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
}

blockquote h3:after{
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}
```

Or like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pz6kx0bw/

Comment: This works well thanks. I used your suggestion using the position attributes

Comment: How about taking your jsfiddle and making it into a stack-snippet so it can be demonstrated right here in your answer?